# SQLite.swift: App crashes due to force-unwrapping a nil value while in active Search tapping a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I've added a `UISearchBar` to my `ViewController` and there's a `UITableView` in it, too, which is "*fed"* by data from an SQLite Database using [SQLite.Swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift).

The search works, all results are displayed correctly while searching. Calling the DetailView by clicking a `TableViewCell` also works fine but when I click on a cell **during** an active search the app crashes.

Strange thing: it works all fine in the simulator without crashing but not on my physical device. I'm using the latest XCode 9 and XCode 9 beta versions and I'm launching the app in iOS 11.3 or 11.4.

I've tried several things but I just can't figure out what causes the crash. I'm pasting the whole `ViewController`. I've marked sections where code is used which is taken from added frameworks/extensions.

**The error says:**

> *"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."*

This is the section where the error refers to in `SQLite.swift`:

```
func value<A: Value>(_ v: Binding?) -> A {
    return value(v!)
}
```

I'm wondering where that `nil` value is.

**Here's my Code:** thanks for hints and help

**EDIT:** I've edited the code because the error didn't occur in the `ViewController` of the active window but in the `DetailViewController` which should be displayed after clicking the `TableViewCell`. This is the line where the error occurs:

This code should find the line in the database where a name and a date match given variables to select the name in that line:

```
let nameOfBank = try! database.scalar(table.filter(tableColumnName == cell?.textLabel?.text && tableColumnDate == cell?.detailTextLabel?.text).select(bankName))
```

Comment: Why would you force-unwrap the optional parameter? That needs to be fixed. Either remove the `?` in the parameter or properly handle a nil value for `v`.

Comment: I doubt it's the source of the crash, but you're never updating `filteredDates` when the search text changes. You might want to create a struct `bankInfo` which contains the name and date; and fill the banksArray with instances of that. Then your filtering will be simpler, having only one array to filter to create filteredBanks, rather than trying to keep two arrays (filteredBanks and filteredDates) in sync.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks but I've ran through all of the optionals and force-unwraps I have in the code and I think I don't understand where to have a closer look. I've changed a few of them and tested some other ways but with the same result (crash). Could you give me another hint what to look at?

Comment: @GrahamPerks thanks. You're right - that's not the reason for the crash but I have tested the struct thing before and since I am a beginner I wasn't able to fill the array as struct or struct as array or however this is called. So I decided to leave this for the future when I'm able to understand a) what this does and b) when this even is :)

Comment: @Aeger I am referring to `func value<A: Value>(_ v: Binding?) -> A { return value(v!) }` which you stated is where the error is.

Comment: @rmaddy oh, that‘s the code from `SQLite.Swift` wrapper. When I change things I‘m buried in errors :D I will try to modify it tonight. First attempts were not successful. Thanks for clearifying.

Comment: OK, I've managed to isolate the source of the error. It's not even in this `ViewController`! It's in the `DetailView` and occurs while unwrapping the single items in the SQLite Database. I have to figure out now how to set these to a correct `query`/`filter`/`scalar`. All these lines are written like that: `let result = try! database.scalar(history.filter(bankName == segueBankName && dateSave == segueBankDate).select(questionsResult))`
Funny thing: I have the exact same `scalar` in another app and there it works. Only difference: I've extended the filter here by adding `&&`
Have to check it

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question after I've found the source of the error.

The error didn't occur in the `ViewController` inside my question. It occurred in `viewDidLoad()` in the `DetailViewController` where I fetched the missing data to be displayed in the details out of the `SQLite` Database.

Here's the solution after research and checking `SQLite.swift`'s GitHub:

To get a column's value of a line where you know two other values already you need to `select` a `binding` from a double `filter`. And that goes like this:

```
let wantedValue = try! database.scalar(history.select(valueLookingFor).filter(knownValue1 == firstKnownValue && knownValue2 == secondKnownValue))
```

No error, no crash anymore.